# Upgrade to TLS 1.2 so I can install packages in Python 3 on macOS 10.13

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, pip, tls1.2

I'm getting errors trying to install packages in Python 3:

```
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) -- Some packages may not be found!
```

I have the following OpenSSL installed:

```
(venv) $ openssl version
LibreSSL 2.2.7
```

I'm using Python 3.5.4 within a virtual environment:

```
(venv) $ python --version
Python 3.5.4
```

After some searchin I believe my errors are caused because macOS uses TLS 1.0 instead of 1.2 (which is required by pip):

```
(venv) $ python -c "import json, urllib.request; print(json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read().decode('UTF-8'))['tls_version'])" 
TLS 1.0
```

Solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284838/python-enable-tls1-2-on-osx) have no effect.

What can I do to make python install packages via pip in a virtual environment without getting the above error?

*(On a side note, I installed Python 2.7.15 and followed the instructions provided in the installer to upgrade to TLS 1.2 with success. However, the Python 3.5.4 installer does not provide the same instructions.)*

*EDIT: uninstalled Homebrew, any Python version I could find except for the system version, etc. etc. Then installed Anaconda3-4.2.0 (this has Python 3.5.2). Problem still persists.*

Comment: Have you tried other 3.X versions?

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino I also tried 3.5.2.

Comment: Sorry, I meant X >= 6